# O que está faltando no listAdapter customizado que criei?

Tags: android, listview

Estou querendo inserir uma listview em um fragment. Quando uso o layout padrão "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" funciona sem problemas, mas quero criar um layout diferente com duas text views por linha.

Fragment - Trechos

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Trechos extends Fragment {

       ListView list;
    private String[] trechos = {"a", "b"};
    private int [] posicao = {1,2};

    @Override
    //Método para inflar o layout
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState){


        //Variável view to tipo View infla o layout a ser usado
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trechos, container, false);

        //retorna a variável view
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

        Classe adapter = new Classe(getContext(), posicao, trechos);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

XML do Fragment trechos

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adaptador customizado

```
package com.example.gabriel.shock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Classe extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private String [] trechos;
    private int [] posicao;

    public Classe(Context context, int [] posicao, String [] trechos) {


        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, trechos);

        this.context = context;
        this.posicao = posicao;
        this.trechos = trechos;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, true);

        TextView txtPosicao = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.posicao);

        TextView txtTrecho = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trechos);

        txtPosicao.setText(posicao[position]);

        txtTrecho.setText(trechos[position]);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

O layout de cada linha

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/posicao"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />


        <TextView
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/trechos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Quando tento rodar com a listview customizada o app da crash:

```
06-21 21:35:05.115 6716-6716/com.example.gabriel.shock E/test: Exception
06-21 21:35:05.135 6716-6716/com.example.gabriel.shock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3805)
                                                                             at com.example.gabriel.shock.Classe.getView(Classe.java:41)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1845)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1661)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2037)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14188)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1953)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4907)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando `int`s para o `setText` do `TextView` na linha

```
txtPosicao.setText(posicao[position]);
```

Isso faz com que seja chamado o método [`setText(int resId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)), que vai tentar definir como texto do `TextView` o que quer que tenha no arquivo `R.java` associado a esse ID. Como, no seu caso, não havia nada (e olha que você deu sorte-- seria uma coincidência difícil de depurar, se houvesse), deu esse erro.

Troque por

```
txtPosicao.setText(String.valueOf(posicao[position]));
```

que vai chamar o método `setText` adequado e o problema vai embora.

Comment: Nossa que desatenção kk, valeu cara vou mudar aqui.

Comment: erro bem comum, principalmente por não acontecer nenhum alerta por parte da IDE durante a escrita do código.

Comment: Cara era isso mesmo, valeu